# Redactor field doesn't display

Tags: redactor

Redactor fields are failing to display for my client and I'm stumped as to what might be happening.

They work fine for me and I haven't heard reports from any of the other 10+ CMS users.

It seems OS/browser specific, because the person that reached out is on a brand new computer running the latest version of Windows 10 and Chrome. When I asked them to test in Firefox everything worked fine.

Some more technical details:

- The site is running Craft 2.6.3017
- Chrome 67.0.3396.87
- Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64
- AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36

It sounds like it could be related to [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26476/redactor-rich-text-field-issue-occurs-in-craft-2-6-3017), but it's not quite the same. Has anyone else heard reports of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was caused by a js error being thrown by an ad blocking plugin the user had installed on his browser.